# Zend form elements coming from a database

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Currently I'm stuck writing a edit function for an order page using zend framework

Here is the situation:

One order consist of multiple items

```
Eg Order Number 1

Consists of Items

OrderListId   OrderId    title      Sent    dateSent     trackingNumber 
     1           1        Book A     0       12/12/12         44444
     2           1        Book B     1       10/01/12         51223
     3           1        Book C     0       01/02/12         33353
     and so on...
```

**Please notes: the table are stored in a database**

I need to have a page where the user can edit title, Sent, dateSent and trackingNumber fields.

How can I use zend form to populate these fields for edit. Since I want to have one page they can edit all these orderlist items. Rather then the user have to click back and forward to edit each order list item individually.

What's the best approach to this situation?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: use [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [ZF Data Grid](http://zfdatagrid.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this awhile back and I came up with a solution where I just appended an update link to the end of the table row and populated a form for update while still displaying current information.

The following code samples were built before I knew what I was doing with ZF so they may be a little messy. I ended up with what amounts to single view that handles all of my CRUD operations.

**All css selectors removed for clarity
The display view:

```
<?php if (isset($this->leadtracks)): ?>
    <form method="post" action="/admin/track/deletetrack">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5"><?php $this->tableHeader() ?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Shift</th>
                <th>Days Off</th>
                <th>Slots</th>
                <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php
                //begin foreach loop using alternate syntax
                foreach ($this->leadtracks as $lt):
                    ?>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="trackid[]"
                               value="<?php
            //trackid as value for checkbox
            echo $lt->trackid
                    ?>" style="width: 2px" /></td>
                    <td><?php
                       //find and display shift name
                       $lt->getShift();
                    ?></td>
                    <td><?php $lt->getDays(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $this->escape($lt['qty'])?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php
                //link to update action passing trackid and bidlocationid values
                echo $this->url(array('module' => 'admin',
                                      'controller' => 'track',
                                      'action' => 'updatetrack',
                                      'trackid' => $lt['trackid'],
                                      'bidlocationid' => $lt['bidlocationid']))
                    ?>">Update</a></td>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete Selected" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- further code removed for brevity -->
</form>
```

The updateAction(), only one action for demonstration:

```
public function updatetrackAction() {

        //get form set new label and assign to view
        $form = new Admin_Form_Track();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Update Track');
        $form->addTrack->setLegend('Update A Track');
        $this->view->form = $form;

        try {
            //check is post and is valid and get values from form
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {

                    $data = $form->getValues();
                    $trackId = $data['trackid'];

                    //save update data to database
                    $update = new Model();
                    $update->update($trackId, $data);
                    //generate meesage
                    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage(Zend_Registry::get('config')
                                                  ->messages->trackupdate->successful);
                    $this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('addtrack');
                } else {
                    //if form is not vaild populate form for resubmission
                    $form->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                }
            } else {
                //if form is not posted populate form with data from database
                $trackId = $this->_getParam('trackid', 0);
                if ($trackId > 0) {
                    $z = new Model();
                    $y = $z->getTrack($trackId)->toArray();
                    $form->populate($y);
                }
            }
        } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
            $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($e->getMessage()->getTrace());
            $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
        }
    }
```

The addAction() and the deleteAction() are very similar and use the same view script called through the action() helper.
 The result is a page in which add, update and delete actions are performed from what the user perceives as one page(check box for multiple deletes and a link for update, every refresh displays current data).
 Although I do move the form from side to side as a sort of visual clue, though it really doesn't matter as all actions are available on each page.

the update view:

```
<div>
    <h3><?php echo ucwords($this->escape(strtoupper($this->station) . ' - ' . $this->bidloc)); //page header ?></h3>
    <?php echo $this->form //edit/add form ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $this->action('displaytrack', 'track', 'admin') //display view ?>
</div>
```

I'm sure this can be done with the partial() view helper, without using the action() helper and I'm sure it can be done inline, I just haven't taken the time to figure out how to do it.

good Luck.